# Why do they teach hyperbolic functions in calculus

Tags: calculus, hyperbolic-functions

I am a student in calculus 2 and I had to learn hyperbolic functions. But why do I have to learn these? And what are the applications? I searched it up and got something vague like it helps describe negative Gaussian curvature, but what does that even mean?

Comment: Also [this is related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/188938/29335)

Comment: Suggested watch: [Calculus Revisited Unit V: Lec 3 | What a Difference a Sign Makes](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-006-calculus-revisited-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/part-v-transcendental-functions/lecture-3-what-a-difference-a-sign-makes/)